# 'For loop' that increments based on minute time trigger as custom timer

Tags: google-sheets

I am not really that good at anything to do with computers generally and tried to create a timer in VBA and on running into roadblocks there (macros would lose functionality when shared) I tried creating the same thing now using Google Sheets, so that it becomes easier to work with shared sheets, but now have a different set of problems:

1) My timer is not actually a timer but just a 'for loop' that increments based on minute time trigger and hence the more cells the slower each subsequent cell timer.

2) When the cell timers run for a while the timer automatically stops and gives me the error message:

> Service using too much computer time for one day

or sometimes

> exceeded maximum execution time

and then I have to manually trigger the timer or wait for the minute time trigger to fire again which would render this sheet useless.

I am pasting the code below if anyone out there would care to help this old timer:

**makelist()** Stores Cell Locations on Another Sheet for the cells that call this function using a Startbutton

```
function makelist() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
 var r = cell.getRow();
 var c = cell.getColumn();
 var list = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
 var i = 1;
 var cell=list.getRange(1,1);
 while( cell.getValue()!= ""){
  i++;
 cell=list.getRange(i,1);
 }
 cell.setValue(r);
 cell=list.getRange(i,2);
 cell.setValue(c);
 }
```

**dellist()** deletes particular cell locations on which the StopButton has been pressed from the list .

```
function dellist(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var r = cell.getRow();
  var c = cell.getColumn();
  var list = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
  var i = 1;
  var cell1=list.getRange(1,1);
  var cell2=list.getRange(1,2);
 while( cell1.getValue() != ""){
  if(cell1.getValue() == r && cell2.getValue() == c){
  list.deleteRow(i);
  }
  i++;
  cell1=list.getRange(i,1);
  cell2=list.getRange(i,2)
  }
  }
```

**addtime()** Increments Active Cells Values by 1 for all cells whose locations are stored in the list.

```
function addtime(){
 var s1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
 var s2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
 var r,c,value,n;
 for(n=1;n<=60;n++)
 { 
  var i=1;
  var cell=s2.getRange(1,1);
  var cell1=s2.getRange(1,2); 

while(cell.getValue()!="")
 {

 r=cell.getValue();
 c=cell1.getValue();
 cell3=s1.getRange(r,c);
 value=cell3.getValue();
 cell3.setValue(value+1);
 i++;
 cell=s2.getRange(i,1);
 cell1=s2.getRange(i,2);
 }
 }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom script associated with the project, code the functions you need there, then set up a trigger when your sheet changes:

[image: On change triggers]

You can find more about custom script functions here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Comment: Thank you @fabrosell for your suggestion..Let me give it a try and get back to you asap.

Comment: Hey @fabrosell...just to make sure we are on the same page aren't the functions I created already custom scripts? And I did have a time trigger set up on the code above for every minute but the trigger fails to execute often giving me those error messages I had written above...am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, custom functions are created in a custom script code. What I think you should do, is to change the timed trigger to an OnChange trigger. Remember Google will automatically stop any function or code who runs for "too much time" with the messages you already experienced.